# Firebase Firestore Add Map item to Array field

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a new record like the one below on the right side of the image to a Firestore document using a function deployed to firebase. The function is developed in typescript:

Function:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const app = express();

app.put('/v2/MYENDPOINT/add', async (req, res) => {
    try 
    {
        const res1 = db.collection('Bars2')
                         .doc('NHn8368LhIhNWHTOaEDo')
                         .update({
                            name: req.body['name'],
                            address: req.body['address1']
                          }).then(function() {
                            res.status(200).send(`Created a new Real bar2: ${(res1)}`)
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            res.status(400).send("Error writing document: " + error);
                        });


        //res.status(200).send(`Created a new Real bar2: ${(res1)}`)
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        res.status(400).send(`Real bar2 not created!!! ${error}`)
    }        
})
```

I try with postman to add this item but the code is not working as I would like:

Postman New Request
{
    "name": "BAR C",
    "address": "qwerty"
}

Any ideas what I am missing from the Update part of the code to add as per the structure on the right? Postman request currently adds as per the item on the left in yellow. Thanks

[Data as I would like to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4tbB.png)

Comment: Use FieldValue.arrayUnion().  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=sr#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: Thanks Doug, I'll give that a go.

Comment: So the only issue I see now is it added the data to a new regions array, not my existing Bars array. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Updated code .update({
                            regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                                name: req.body['name'],
                                address: req.body['address1']
                              })
                            }).

Comment: Don't blindly copy the code - provide the name of the field you want to update in the call as illustrated in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I see it now, I thought regions was part of the firebase keywords.